# about java sql connection in ubuntu latest version using eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, connector, ubuntu-20.04

i had installed java jdk version 8 and also set the home and path ,also installed eclipse .But when i try to connect java with mysql database ,the sqlconnector jar file is not shown in my jre environment library .So i got class not not found error.I also refreshed it many times ,but not visible yet.I also added it to my project folder and created build path.I also installed Xampp .what will i do .Please help me...